# NoClassDefFoundError for DataSourceFactory on starting Tomcat9 server?

Tags: java, tomcat, datasource, server.xml

I am deploying a JAR file to the `classpath/lib` folder which contains the customized subclass of `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory` and I am feeding it as a factory class for dataSource's `Resource` tag in `server.xml`. The appropriate libraries are being added (Hence no compile time error) but on starting the server it is giving the the following error log and failing to start :

```
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8013]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/DataSourceFactory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.naming.factory.FactoryBase.getObjectInstance(FactoryBase.java:61)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:840)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:159)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:827)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.addResource(NamingContextListener.java:1015)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.createNamingContext(NamingContextListener.java:556)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.lifecycleEvent(NamingContextListener.java:252)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:762)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 32 more
```

Can anybody help me? any information will be helpful. Thank you in advance ;-)

Comment: You probably forgot to put the jdbc-driver in the scope of your tomcat's or your application's lib folder. Remember that the compiled source code of a web app usually doesn't contain dependant libs, which have to be deployed with the web application explicitly, or (if you are using an IDE without an explicit build script) have to be reexported and redeployed.

Comment: @TreffnonX Thanks for the answer ;-). After your answer, I tried adding the Apache-jdbc.jar in a lib forlder INSIDE my jar and added that as a reference jar in build path. but it is still giving the same error ;-(. Before that I was adding Tomcat's lib folder as external library (coz it has all the required jars) and it was adding that into the ".classpath" file (I checked) still it was giving the same error. It is giving the error only for "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" not other referenced libraries. confusing :-(

Comment: What database are you trying to connect to? You need to find and download the database specific jdbc-driver. Apache-jdbc.jar is apache's connection pool, not a jdbc driver. Try googling your database's name and jdbc, and you will probably find what you need. Or do you mean hive-apache-jdbc?

Comment: @TreffnonX I am working on postgres database, I added its driver jar also in the lib folder. But it is giving the same error, I am starting to feel that maybe the issue is not related to the JARs.